# Thread Not Acting Asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, web-services

I've got a WPF application written in C#.  It makes a call to a WCF service I wrote.  At times, the WCF service could take up to 20 seconds to return (depending on if it needs to refresh data).  I know I can make the WCF service support asynchronous calls, but another solution I thought would work would be to wrap the call to the WCF service into a new thread.  I did so with the following code:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(
    new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
    delegate()
    {
        Action del = delegate()
        {
            MyService.MyServiceClient ms = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
            lblTotalCost.Text = ms.GetTotalCost().ToString("C");
        };

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(del);
    })).Start();
```

I put this into the constructor function of one of my UserControls, after InitializeComponent().

Without it, the application won't appear until the service call completes.  My hope was that adding this would make it so that the application would appear immediately and that the label would populate once the service call completed.  To my surprise though, this did not happen.  The application still does not appear until the service call completes.

How does this need to be modified so that it does what I intended it to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Dispatcher` you put **all** the work back on the UI-thread. Only the assignment to `lblTotalCost.Text` should be done there i suppose.

```
MyService.MyServiceClient ms = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
var value = ms.GetTotalCost().ToString("C");

this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lblTotalCost.Text = value));
```

Comment: Much better!  Thanks!  Thought that might be the case, but didn't want to just implement the change without understanding what was going on or confirming the theory was true.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating another thread which immediately calls back to your UI thread to do the actual work (via that `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call).

What you want is for the background thread to do the long-running work, ***then*** call back to the UI:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(
new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
delegate()
{
    MyService.MyServiceClient ms = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
    var v = ms.GetTotalCost();
    Action del = delegate()
    {
        lblTotalCost.Text = v.ToString("C");
    };

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(del);
})).Start();
```